# Get product category based on url, not all categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have my product permalink set as "Shop base with category" (e.g.  `/shop/%product_cat%/`). So when viewing a product it will resemble something like:

```
http://www.example.com/shop/foo/test-product/
```

I'd like to fetch the "foo" category. I've found proposed solutions which use the `get_the_terms` function to look up a product's categories, but if the product is in multiple categories then there is no way to know which category is refelcted in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be possible to use [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) to get the query variable from the URL.

```
$cat = get_query_var( 'product_cat' );
```